# Rails: How to migrate without triggering foreign key checks (referential integrity checks)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, referential-integrity

I need to change the column type of all primary keys in all tables to the `UUID` format.

How do I migrate without triggering the foreign key checks?

I have tried the following 2 things below, but both still trigger the error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'fk_rails_6010a70481' of table 'project_development.some_other_table'
```

.

```
class JustAnotherMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]

  def change
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disable_referential_integrity do
      change_column :cities, :id, :uuid
    end
  end

end
```

.

```
class JustAnotherMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]

  def change
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;"
    change_column :cities, :id, :uuid
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;"
  end

end
```

Rails version: `7.0.4.3`

MariaDB version: `11.1.2`

Comment: Wouldn't you want to fix all the FKs too? Otherwise you'll end up with broken data and incompatible column types.

Comment: @muistooshort - thank you, yes. I just thought any solution would then be the same for the FKs.

Comment: No - your foreign key column would contain a bunch of numerical ids that would'nt work any more. You need to create a separate UUID column for all the cities records and a seperate foreign key column on the table that references it. That way you can fill the new  foreign key column while using the old ids to find the correct record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have woefully underestimated how much of a ordeal changing the primary key type is. If you want to change the primary key type beyond just changing numerical types you have to actually update all the related tables first to avoid orphaning the records in thoses tables.

The outline of the process is:

1. Backup your database.
2. Create a `cities.uiid` UUID type column. Don't touch the `id` column for now.
3. Create a `other_table.city_uuid` column. It should be nullable and you can skip the foreign key constraint for now.
4. Fill the `other_table.city_uuid` with the `cities.uiid`. This can either be done with `OtherModel.include(:city).find_each { |om| om.update(city_uuid: om.city.uiid) }` or by using `UPDATE ALL` with a subquery or lateral join. The former is sufficient for small data sets and the later will be faster by an order of magintidue as it doesn't result in N+1 write queries.
5. Now that you're done recreating the relation between the tables remove the `other_table.city_id` column. This will take care of the foreign key restraint problem.
6. Remove `cities.id`. This may require you to remove the index first.
7. Rename `cities.uuid` to `cities.id`.
8. Rename `other_table.city_uuid` to `other_table.city_id`, add a foreign key constraint and make it non-nullable (if that's applicable).

The steps 3-5 must be repeated for every foreign key column in your schema.

Comment: You missed step 1b: Verify that your database backup worked by restoring it to a separate server.

Comment: @muistooshort I skipped a whole lot of verification steps for brevity.